# How to redirect to a file

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a question regarding the rewrite rule in my app. One of my JS files that is built by other team request a file that is not in our domain. I am trying to set a rewrite rule to make it redirect to another page in my .htaccess. file when the file request happens.

For example:
My current console log shows

```
GET http://example.com/file.object?_=1234 404 (Not Found)
```

I want to redirect it to

```
http://example.com/processLink to process the correct file.
```

My rewrite rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /file.object
RewriteRule ^.*$ /processLink/ [R=302]
```

It doesn't work. I am a bit rusty on the rewrite rules. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Do you want to handle all `/file.object` links OR just `/file.object?_=1234` link?

Comment: @anubhava I need to handle all /file.object link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^file\.object$ /processLink? [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: I have ?_=1234 at the end of .object. Doest .object$ apply? Your rewrite rule doesn't seem to work for me + 1

Comment: Query string isn't matched in `RewriteRule` so `$` won't affect anything after `?`. Make sure this is very first rule just below `RewriteEngine` line.

Answer (score 1):

I would change it to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/file\.object /processLink [R=302]
```